# AWS dynamobd query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to know that with the partition key the id that my search for metatdata looking for a key actually does just that.  The result of this query

```
 aws dynamodb query --table-name name-of-table --key-condition-expression 'id = :idval' --filter-expression 'key = :keyval' --expression-attribute-values '{":idval": {"S":"91"},":keyval":{"S":"PROFILEA", "S":"PROFILEB", "S":"PROFILEC"}}'
```

is:

```
{    
  "Items": [],
  "Count": 0,
  "ScannedCount": 0,
  "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name name-of-table --key-condition-expression 'id = :idval' --filter-expression 'key IN :keyval' --expression-attribute-values '{":idval": {"S":"91"},":keyval":[{"S":"PROFILEA"},{"S":"PROFILEB"},{"S":"PROFILEC"}]}'
```